# Rambam Epistle to Yemen identification

Tags: history, rambam

In [Rambam's Epistle](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Epistle_to_Yemen/IV), he mentions three groups that challenged the Jewish people by coming up with a new religion. He mentions Jesus first and Islam (who he refers to as the Madman) last. However, he mentions a middle group without giving a name. Who is this group?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Albert. The Epistle is quite long. Would you care to [edit] in a more precise location for this claim? [Here](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Epistle_to_Yemen) is an English translation from Wikisource that can be linked to. Hope to see you around!

Answer (score 2):

According to the footnote [here](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Epistle_to_Yemen/Complete#N2), this refers to Paul and his ilk, "whom Maimonides correctly understood to be the real founders of Christianity".

Comment: Yes, so that is an interesting idea. But I am not sure what he means when he says that they put this religion down, that just seems incorrect if we are talking about Paul. Though there is no guarantee that Rambam had correct knowledge of Christianity. Also, it is curious that in Twersky's Maimondies Reader he does not leave a note saying the same thing, though he does leave a note telling us who are the Muslims. I have a hunch that this wiki source note might be taking a guess.

Comment: @Albert, I suppose any statement about what he was referring to may be a guess, but if you want a named scholar who agrees, [here](http://www.manfredlehmann.com/sieg96.html) is one.

Comment: @ Albert, some of that additional information is directly relevant and deserves to be edited into the question. And the second part of your comment deserves its own question. @Yishai It's not anonymous. It is attributed to [Abraham Halkin](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/3622651?sid=21105825194443&uid=2&uid=4).

Answer (score 1):

In Prof. Abraham Halkin's own English translation with notes of the epistle (Crisis and Leadership: Epistles of Maimonides, pg. 134 note 46), he translates slightly different than Boaz Cohen* as follows:

> Quite some time later [than Jesus], a religion, which is traced to him by the descendants of Esau, gained popularity. Although this was the aim he hoped to realize, he had no impact on Israel, as neither groups nor individuals became unsettled in their beliefs...

and notes as follows:

> The assertion is explicit. Jesus was called the founder of a new religion some centuries after his death by "the descendants of Esau," i.e. the Romans, but he had nothing to do with it, and never considered it; and what he did was not a source of harm to Israel. The history of the rise of Christianity was current among Jewish writers in medieval times.

Thus it appears that the second category is a reference to Christianity, whereas the first is only to Jesus himself.

*The one linked from Wikipedia. Contrary to the indication there, the notes to that English text is from an edition containing a dual translation, "אגרת תימן, האקדמיה האמריקנית למדעי היהדות, תשי״ב" (see [this](http://www.otzar.org/book.asp?10462) or [this](https://m.ebay.com/itm/Epistle-Yemen-ARABIC-HEBREW-/372025260507?_mwBanner=1)), in which the Hebrew version was translated and notated by Halkin whereas the English by Cohen)